# Raspberry Pi - is it possible to restart a python program, if an error occures and interrupts the running code?

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi

I was wondering if it was possible to restart a python program (automatically ofc, preferably with an easy script) it case it encounters a problem and closes it. My algorithm sometimes doesn't function the way I want it to, but it doesn't really matter if I am able to get it to restart.

Code:

```
dongle = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate=9600,timeout=0,rtscts=0,xonxoff=0)
ard = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=9600)
time.sleep(0.5)
while True:
#       ard.open()
        discard = ard.readline()
        string = ard.readline()
        print discard
        print string
        time.sleep(0.5)
        temperature, truebung, latitude, longtitude  = string.split(",")
```

Basically, what's happening once every 10 times, is that "string" is corrupt. It does not give me the data I want it to. It misses something or gives me a random value. Normally, the string should look something like this "24.04,0.23,18.92442,40.25255" but it sometimes is corrupt and looks like this "40.25255" or ".25255". I "ard.readline" twice because originally, the "discard" was always corrupt, now the string is also corrupt. What can I do to fix that? It doesn't matter if string isn't correct once every 10 times but it crashes my program and that's the thing I want it not to do.

Comment: This [question](http://superuser.com/questions/507576/how-to-automatically-restart-a-linux-background-process-if-it-fails) could already give you an idea

Comment: You _could_ do that, but it would be better to catch the problem inside the program and deal with it. We really need to see some code, preferably a [mcve], to give more specific details.

Comment: @PM2Ring added information.

Comment: Am I correct that your program crashes on this line: `temperature, truebung, latitude, longtitude  = string.split(",")` with ValueError? I.e. is the error message `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got [x])`?

Comment: I don't know Raspberry Pi, but I suggest you change the way you assign to `temperature, truebung, latitude, longtitude`. Split the string. If it has the correct number of fields, then attempt to convert them to float inside a `try...except ValueError` block. If the exception isn't raised, you _probably_ have valid data, but you should perform checks on each of the the values to ensure they are within a sane range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and assume that your program crashes with `ValueError` on the last line:

```
temperature, truebung, latitude, longtitude  = string.split(",")
```

when there aren't enough elements. The error should be something like `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got [x])` If so, the fix is pretty simple. The code below should prevent your program from crashing if I guessed your error code correctly.

```
try:
    temperature, truebung, latitude, longtitude  = string.split(",")
except ValueError:
    print "corrupt string" # and whatever else you want to do to handle the error
```

Comment: that's exactly the error I'm getting. If I'm not getting that error, will it just continue past the "try..except" block? If so, if there a way to jump to the start of the "while True:" - loop when "ValueError = True"?

Comment: if you are not getting the error, it will do what the `try`-block does, if there is an error, it will do what the `except` specifies. In either case, it will jump back to the start of your loop.

Comment: @anthrx to go to the beginning of the loop you would just do `... except ValueError: continue`

Comment: @ChristianW. Thanks a lot buddy, that worked perfectly. Everything has been solved.